# How do you get route values in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there an alternative to get the route value in the view page instead of read it like querystring?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Language Resources", "Index", "LanguageResource", 
                 new { languageCode = Request.QueryString["languageCode"] , "")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't rule out keeping it simple:

```
public ActionResult Action(int id)
{
    return View( id);
}
```

Indicate the type of the Model we're dealing with

```
@model int
```

And refer to the value in a strongly typed way via:

```
@Model
```

Answer (score 109):

try to find from below code

In Razor

```
@{
    var id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
 }
```

In WebForms:

```
<% 
    var id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
%>
```

Comment: that returns object, how to convert to diff type ?

Comment: @Nigel `int id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as int;`

Comment: Oops, forgot we're dealing with a ValueType. `int? id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as int?;` Cast it to [Nullable<int>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) AKA `int?`, then check if it's null.

Answer (score 26):

You can use RequestContext

```
@{
var id = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

And for the less experienced out there, you can access the controller and the action parts of the URL too.
(Razor Example)

```
if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "Account")
{
    @Html.Raw("Hi ") @Session["UserName"]
}
```

Where,

```
context.MapRoute(
            name: "MyRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
}
```